# VPN from home to office to AWS

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, remote, netgear

I have a remote access VPN set up so developers can access our internal network. I also have an IPSec VPN setup so the personnel that are physically at the office can access the AWS servers.

What I need to do is setup this network so that a developer can VPN to the office then utilize the AWS VPN to access those servers. Right now I can not access anything on the AWS side unless I am physically at the office.

I am using a netgear FVS336gv2 firewall: 
I have tried mode config for the remote access vpn, thinking that if the developer was assigned an IP address within the LAN they should be able to access the AWS side, this however does not work.

How do I go about implementing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has been answered already. You might be experiencing an issue with multiple VPNs as described below:

> To avoid issues with multiple VPN, you should endeavour to use more "controlled" forms of VPN. For instance, a SOCKS proxy with ssh. This would allow you to run one Web browser which redirect all its traffic to another host (the "VPN server") while leaving the rest of the machine (and, crucially, other browser instances) unaltered. See this answer for instance. Some purists say that such proxying is not a VPN, but for many practical purposes (anything which is Web-based, really), this is functionally equivalent. See also the alternative with port-based tunnels. I used to do that a lot at one time (a dozen or so port-based tunnels, and also SOCKS proxying, and it was all working well). The SOCKS solution works well for name resolution too: the name resolutions requests from the Web browser will go through the tunnel, to be resolved on the other side (i.e. in the VPN), without touching the local DNS configuration. Port-based tunnels require a static local name declaration.

```
Source: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31030/connect-through-two-vpn-clients
```

I have done a quick search for you and found:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Amazon%20SOCKS%20proxy
```

I suspect that your issue is a VPN conflict, although I could be wrong, try and implemenet a SOCKS proxy and see if that works for you. I know from experience that if I remote in from home (Not VPN direct connection, so I use an RDP Server or Teamviewer) I can then VPN/pivot down into another network. But to use something like AnyConnect -> HotSpot as previously mentioned I doubt would work, however, I stand to be corrected (hopefully!).